# Angularjs controller not working, throws error (newbie)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, single-page-application

i'm working with angular-seed project.
I'm trying to retreive data from mysql database.
I need to know how to define different controller for each view.
For example, I have this structure:

```
js
|_modules
  |_companies
     |_controller.js
     |_data.js
|_app.js
|_base.js
```

I have added this route to **app.js**

```
.state('app.companies', {
    url: '/companies',
    title: 'Companies',
    templateUrl: helper.basepath('companies.html'),
    controller: 'companiesCtrl' //THIS THROWS THE ERROR BELOW
})
```

**companies.html** has scripts added to botom of the page

```
<script src="app/js/modules/companies/data.js"></script>
<script src="app/js/modules/companies/controller.js"></script>
```

and this is the code for **controller.js** (also tested the commented part)

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('appname')
        .controller('companiesCtrl', companiesCtrl);

    companiesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','companiesData','$log'];
    function companiesCtrl($scope, companiesData, $log) {
        console.log('asd'); //NEVER REACH THIS LOG
    };
});

/*var app = angular
.module('appname')
.controller('companiesCtrl', ['$scope','companiesData','$log', function($scope, companiesData, $log){
console.log('asd'); //NEVER REACH THIS LOG
$scope.companies = {};
Data.get('companies').then(function(data){
    $scope.companies = data.data;
    console.log('($scope.companies)');
});
}]);
*/
```

But I keep getting

> **Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'companiesCtrl' is not a function, got undefined**

Same if I script `ng-controller="companiesCtrl"` on my view.

Comment: can you post the content of your `app.js` and possibly your view?

Comment: i think you have to execute your function (function(){   'use strict'  ..... })();

Comment: @Amir, it is a compiled code of several js files. At least 1800+ lines. Is there anything specific that you want to know? I will post it.

Comment: I thought the problem might be somewhere else, but someone already posted an answer and I guess that might be it. You have to call that anonymous function :)

Comment: @leandronn see my answer may be it will help you

Comment: Tried but with no good results. Error is the same when declaring companiesCtrl. If I change the declarations of scrpts controller.js and data.js to index.html, it works fine. But when I move then to view (companies.html) the undefined error shows in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on script loading.
I had to use lazy loading of the files within my app.js
Here's the code:

app.js companies route

```
.state('app.companies', {
          url: '/companies',
          title: 'Companies',
          templateUrl: helper.basepath('companies.html'),
          resolve: helper.resolveFor('companiesCtrl'),
          controller: 'companiesCtrl'
      })
```

lazy load code

```
.constant('APP_REQUIRES', {
      scripts: {
        'modernizr':          ['vendor/modernizr/modernizr.custom.js'],
        'icons':              ['vendor/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
                               'vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css'],
        'companiesCtrl':      ['app/js/modules/companies/data.js','app/js/modules/companies/controller.js']
      },
      modules: []
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

change your function to:

```
(function() {    
 'use strict';

    angular
        .module('appname')
        .controller('companiesCtrl', companiesCtrl);

    companiesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','companiesData','$log'];
    function companiesCtrl($scope, companiesData, $log) {
        console.log('asd'); //NEVER REACH THIS LOG
    };
})();// execute this function then it will work
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/wk6xhy3k/)  if you remove `()` breaket then it will give you the error.

If possible then create controller like this:

```
angular.module('appname')
  .controller('companiesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      console.log('asd'); //NEVER REACH THIS LOG
}]);
```

Comment: Ok, this is working but **only** if I declare scripts in my index.html page. It does not work if I declare scripts in the view companies.html. There is the real problem, I cannot make different controllers for different views.

Comment: are you talking about  fiddle ?

Comment: No, about my code. If i declare the scripts controller.js and data.js in my view, I keep getting the same error.

Comment: @leandronn see my updated answer i think at this line companiesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','companiesData','$log']; it will give you error

Comment: Tried it but same error. I found the solution and posted it. Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your controller as :

```
(function() {
'use strict';
   function companiesCtrl($scope, companiesData, $log) {
    console.log('asd'); //NEVER REACH THIS LOG
    };

   angular
    .module('appname')
    .controller('companiesCtrl', companiesCtrl);

     companiesCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','companiesData','$log'];

})();
```

Comment: it does not matter if you define the function first or later. If you use `function fn() {}` syntax, it will be defined in preprocess.

Comment: Agree with Amir. Same happens. Thanks.